# internal protected property still accessible from a different assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I'm setting up some demo code for a beginner session on accessibility and I found that I am able to access an internal protected property from a derived class. What am I missing?

**Assembly 1**

```
namespace Accessibility
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ExampleClass c = new ExampleClass();
            c.Go();
            //c.Prop1 = 10;
        }
    }

    class ExampleClass : DerivedClass
    {
        public void Go()
        {
            this.Prop1 = 10;
            this.Prop2 = 10;
            //this.Prop3 = 10; //Doesn't work
            //this.Prop4 = 10; //Doesn't work
            this.Prop5 = 10; //why does this work?!

            this.DoSomething();
        }
    }
}
```

**Assembly 2**

```
namespace Accessibility.Models
{
    public class BaseClass
    {
        public int Prop1 { get; set; }
        protected int Prop2 { get; set; }
        private int Prop3 { get; set; }

        internal int Prop4 { get; set; }
        internal protected int Prop5 { get; set; }
        //internal public int Prop6 { get; set; } //Invalid 
        //internal private int Prop7 { get; set; } //Invalid

        public BaseClass()
        {
            this.Prop3 = 27;
        }
    }

    public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
    {
        public void DoSomething()
        {
            this.Prop1 = 10;
            this.Prop2 = 10;
            //this.Prop3 = 10; //Doesn't work
            this.Prop4 = 10;
            this.Prop5 = 10;

            PropertyInfo Prop3pi = typeof(DerivedClass).GetProperty("Prop3", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
            int value = (int)Prop3pi.GetValue(this, null);
        }
    }
}
```

Notice in ExampleClass.Go I can set a value to Prop5. Why? It's marked as internal protected but I can't set a value on Prop4 (marked as internal)

Comment: Because it is *internal* OR *protected*.  Not AND.

Comment: I didn't think it was OR either

Comment: @Daniel, Where would google take you to answer the question, StackOverflow? You shouldn't down vote because its an easy question, thats meant for poor quality, hard to understand questions.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth I searched but for internal and protected individually, not together. Obvisouly, with the tons of answers I feel a bit silly.

Comment: @Kratz: Just google yourself. It takes you to all the links provided in the answers below. I downvote questions people that can't or don't want to use google.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

`internal protected` means "internal to the assembly OR an inherited class". So yes, if you have a public class with an protected internal member, another class that inherits that type in a different assembly can still access it because of the protected modifier:

> protected internal
>
> The type or member can be accessed by any code in the assembly in which it is declared, **or** from within a derived class in another assembly. Access from another assembly must take place within a class declaration that derives from the class in which the protected internal element is declared, and it must take place through an instance of the derived class type.

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx

This is a limitation of the C# language. The CLR supports the "Internal AND Protected" notion. There is evidence of this with the [`MethodAttributes.FamANDAssem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.methodattributes(v=VS.100).aspx) enumeration if you were emitting your own IL. If you *really*  wanted this feature, you could do some IL post processing with something like Mono.Cecil. Why the C# language does not expose this is only a guess: little need for it.

Answer (score 6):

Because it's how `internal protected` is intended to work. Access is given for either children in inheritance tree (`protected` part) or for the same assembly (`internal` part) - see [Access Modifiers on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx).

And your `ExampleClass` is in the inheritance tree of `BaseClass`, which defines `Prop5`. So the access is thanks to `protected` part.

Comment: i like the simple explanation.

Answer (score 3):

By combining the protected and internal keywords, a class member can be marked protected internal — only derived types or types within the same assembly can access that member.

[This MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121.aspx) answers all your questions.

Comment: So it's either or, not limited to it's most restricted keyword?

Comment: That's correct.  Protected internal means both the derived types (protected) and  the assembly (internal) can access it.  That only applies to the internal modifier.  You can't combine others.

Answer (score 3):

The protected keyword is a member access modifier. A protected member is accessible from within the class in which it is declared, and from within any class derived from the class that declared this member.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bcd5672a(v=vs.71).aspx

By combining the protected and internal keywords, a class member can be marked protected internal — only derived types or types within the same assembly can access that member.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173121(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 3):

It looks like protected internal means [protected or internal](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/10/29/what-does-protected-internal-mean.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

Basically, it doesn't seem to work like that.

See - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ba0a1yw2(VS.80).aspx

protected internal acts as an OR - access is restricted to derived classes or to the current assembly.

Answer (score 1):

`Protected` means that it is shared only with descendant classes, only `private` means that it can't be accessed by anyone else.

Edit: Hans comment makes your question a little more clear. When you combine modifiers like that, they combine inclusively not exclusively. It is accesse in all the ways `internal` or `protected` can be.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but I got caught with the same issue. Eventualy I came up with a partial solution.

```
    internal Int MyInt
    {
        get;
        protected set;
    }
```

It is still visible within the assembly but at least only inherithing classes can actualy change it. It is enough for what I wanted.